# Fusion core plugin - Download failed. A valid URL was not provided

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been having a series of Wordpress problems. This is what happened.

site: frankfortergroup.com

-Did some work saved it and preview. everything was good.

-2 days later everything broke, looked like the theme failed completely. Menu was blow out of proportion, page items all over the place, looked like css is voided. There's also a form with a submit button and a choose file that appeared on all pages at the top, even in the WP dashboard. (I didn't do this).In the WP dashboard -> pages -> any page, I get an error that the Fusion Builder timed out. Tells me to check the System Status, PHP Max Input Vars: was in red and set to 1000. I was able to modify the value through the creation of a .user.ini file. Now the System Status is green. Site is still broken.

-Dis activated all plugins. Tried uninstalling Fusion Core and reinstalling it. Now it won't reinstall.

```
Error: Download failed. A valid URL was not provided.

Plugin not activated. A higher version of Fusion Core is needed for 
this theme. Please update the plugin.
```

The theme I'm running is Avada 4.0.1

I also get errors installing any other plugin or updating them. When I post a page or change a theme setting and try to save I get an alert saying "There was a problem with your action.Please try again or reload the page".

HELP appreciated :)